# mySql: gets the rows where the number of words in the cell (string comma separated) has the same value as a matched cell

Tags: mysql, database, string, csv, where-clause

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tab1 ( 
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
  cod TEXT,
  type TEXT,
  qta INTEGER);

INSERT INTO tab1 (cod, type, qta) 
  VALUES ('aaa','aaa,bbb,ccc', 3),
          ('aaa','ddd', 1),
          ('aaa','eee,fff', 4),
          ('aaa','ggg,hhh', 2),
          ('aaa','out', 7),
          ('aaa','out', 7);
```

I would like to know how many words there are in each cell of column 'type'.

The best for me is to have only the rows that the number of words are the same of 'qta'.

So I would like to have only the rows with id 1, 2, 4

Original link to code: [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d348366/1)

Comment: What in cases of *"empty"* items like `aaa,bbb,` or `ddd,` can it happen?  Also ideally you should normalize..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

```
select *
from tab1
where char_length(type) - char_length(replace(type, ',', '')) + 1 = qta
```

Expression `char_length(type) - char_length(replace(type, ',', ''))` gives you the number of commas in the string. Adding `1` to that gives you the number of words in the string.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9754c0c5af423787ebf750468bb3a619)**:

```
id | cod | type        | qta
-: | :-- | :---------- | --:
 1 | aaa | aaa,bbb,ccc |   3
 2 | aaa | ddd         |   1
 4 | aaa | ggg,hhh     |   2
```

Comment: Thanks so much... and if I need to update the string like this aaa_1,bbb_1,ccc_1

Comment: *"and if I need to update the string like this aaa_1,bbb_1,ccc_1 "*  @FrancescoG. that is a other non related question to your question above more or less requires you writting a complete new question ...